# How can I diagnose why my bot isn't working with Skype?

Tags: azure, botframework

My Bot Service in Azure was working fine with Skype, but after I deployed a new version, the "Health" under Channels showed an issue: "There was a problem synchronizing your bot to Skype." Here's what I did to try to resolve this:

- I edited and saved the channel configuration again, and the Health turned back to a green "Running". However, the new Intent I had added would not work (it returned an error message).
- So I redeployed the Bot Service, but it didn't make a difference.
- Next I deleted the Skype channel and added it again, and now messages sent to the bot via Skype don't even send (they show the warning triangle and say "Not sent!").

Despite this, my Bot Service is showing the Skype channel as "Running" in green and Application Insights is showing no exceptions, but I can't send messages to the bot via Skype. It works fine via the web control. How can I understand why the Skype channel isn't working and fix it?

**UPDATE**: Clicking on Skype in Channels takes me to a page that now says "Oops, there was a problem with your link" and "The bot was not found." Still green and "Running" under Channels next to Skype, however.

**UPDATE2**: Edited the Channel settings again, and now the bot is found and Skype opens, but it still won't let me sent a message to the bot.

Comment: Please try adding the MS Teams channel configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ngrok to debug any channel locally.  This should help you diagnose your problem since your bot is active on skype now.  [Here is a good blog](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) to follow that will instruct you how to do so.